# Pure CSS Slider / Carousel / Slideshow with Autoplay / Animation and Navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, slideshow, autoplay

Can someone please tell me whether it is possible to combine these two into one using only Html & CSS ? (either by autoplay, animation or any other possible way) This question seemed to pop up in the past but always without the answer. This is where I got to.

https://jsfiddle.net/e0g4a1w1/10/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=e0g4a1w1

```
<ul class="rotator">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>

<div class= "rotator">
<span id="item-1"></span>
<span id="item-2"></span>
<span id="item-3"></span>

<div class="carousel-item item-1">
<a class="arrow-prev" href="#item-3"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 
0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-
12.17-11.996z"/></svg></a>
<span>Item 1</span>
<a class="arrow-next" href="#item-2"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 
0 24 24"><path d="M7.33 24l-2.83-2.829 9.339-9.175-9.339-9.167 2.83-2.829 
12.17 11.996z"/></svg></a>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item item-2">
<a class="arrow-prev" href="#item-1"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 
0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-
12.17-11.996z"/></svg></a>
<span>Item 2</span>
<a class="arrow-next" href="#item-3"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 
0 24 24"><path d="M7.33 24l-2.83-2.829 9.339-9.175-9.339-9.167 2.83-2.829 
12.17 11.996z"/></svg></a>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item item-3">
<a class="arrow-prev" href="#item-2"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 
0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-
12.17-11.996z"/></svg></a>
<span>Item 3</span>
<a class="arrow-next" href="#item-1"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 
0 24 24"><path d="M7.33 24l-2.83-2.829 9.339-9.175-9.339-9.167 2.83-2.829 
12.17 11.996z"/></svg></a>
</div>
</div>
----
CSS
---
.rotator {
list-style: none;
font-size: 65px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 35%;
width: 100%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
}

.rotator > li {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
top: 35%;
width: 100%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center; 
}

.rotator > li:first-child {
animation: loop 7s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:nth-child(2) {
animation: opsecond 7s infinite;
}

.rotator > li:last-child {
animation: oplast 7s infinite;
}

@keyframes loop {
0% { opacity: 0; }
10% { opacity: 1; }
33% { opacity: 1; } 
44% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes opsecond {
33% { opacity: 0; }
44% { opacity: 1; }
66% { opacity: 1; }
77% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes oplast {
66% { opacity: 0; }
77% { opacity: 1; }
100% { opacity: 1; }
0% { opacity: 1; }
10% { opacity: 0; }
}

.carousel-wrapper{
height:300px;
position:relative;
width:400px;
}

.carousel-item{
position:absolute;
top: 35%;
width: 100%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center; 
opacity:0;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


[id^="item"] {
  display: none;
}

.item-1 {
   z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}

*:target ~ .item-1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#item-1:target ~ .item-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#item-2:target ~ .item-2, #item-3:target ~ .item-3 {
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: What you want is unclear. "These two" what into "one" what?

Comment: It seems that I have found the answer. http://cssslider.com/wordpress-slideshow-32.html This is what I wanted but with the text only version.

Answer (score 0):

Is to close to what you are looking for so maybe this could help you:

https://codepen.io/miriamcc/pen/KzGGqZ

```css
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.radio {
  /*display: none;*/
}
.images {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.images-inner {
  width: 500%;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}
.image-slide {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
.image-slide,
.fake-radio,
.radio-btn {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.fake-radio {
  float: right;
}




/* Move slides overflowed container */
#slide1:checked ~ .images .images-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}
#slide2:checked ~ .images .images-inner {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
#slide3:checked ~ .images .images-inner {
  margin-left: -200%;
}




/* Color of bullets */
#slide1:checked ~ div .fake-radio .radio-btn:nth-child(1),
#slide2:checked ~ div .fake-radio .radio-btn:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked ~ div .fake-radio .radio-btn:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
}
.radio-btn {
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: gray;
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin: 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Color of bullets - END */




/* Text of slides */
#slide1:checked ~ .labels .label:nth-child(1),
#slide2:checked ~ .labels .label:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked ~ .labels .label:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}

.label {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
/* Text of slides - END */



/* Calculate AUTOPLAY for BULLETS */
@keyframes bullet {
  0%, 33.32333333333334%    {
    background: red;
  }
  33.333333333333336%, 100% {
    background: gray;
  }
}


#play1:checked ~ div .fake-radio .radio-btn:nth-child(1) {
  animation: bullet 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
}

#play1:checked ~ div .fake-radio .radio-btn:nth-child(2) {
  animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 3100ms;    
}

#play1:checked ~ div .fake-radio .radio-btn:nth-child(3) {
  animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 7200ms;    
}
/* Calculate AUTOPLAY for BULLETS - END */




/* Calculate AUTOPLAY for SLIDES */
@keyframes slide {
  0%, 25.203252032520325%   { margin-left: 0; }
  33.333333333333336%, 58.53658536585366%   { margin-left: -100%; }
  66.66666666666667%, 91.869918699187%  { margin-left: -200%; }
}


.st-slider > #play1:checked ~ .images .images-inner {
  animation: slide 12300ms infinite;    
}
/* Calculate AUTOPLAY for SLIDES - END */





/* Calculate AUTOPLAY for CAPTION */
@keyframes caption {
  0%, 33.32333333333334%    {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.333333333333336%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


#play1:checked ~ .labels .label:nth-child(1) {
  animation: caption 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
}

#play1:checked ~ .labels .label:nth-child(2) {
  animation: caption 12300ms infinite 3100ms;   
}

#play1:checked ~ .labels .label:nth-child(3) {
  animation: caption 12300ms infinite 7200ms;   
}
/* Calculate AUTOPLAY for CAPTION - END */
```

```html
<h1>Pure CSS slider</h1><pre>(with Autoplay at the beginning)</pre><br>
<div id="homepage-slider" class="st-slider">

    <input type="radio" class="cs_anchor radio" name="slider" id="slide1"/>
    <input type="radio" class="cs_anchor radio" name="slider" id="slide2"/>
    <input type="radio" class="cs_anchor radio" name="slider" id="slide3"/>
    <input type="radio" class="cs_anchor radio" name="slider" id="play1" checked=""/>

    <div class="images">
       <div class="images-inner">
        <div class="image-slide">
          <div class="image bg-yellow" style="background-color:yellow;">image slide 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-slide">
          <div class="image bg-blue" style="background-color:pink;">imager slide 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-slide">
          <div class="image bg-red" style="background-color:orange;">image slide 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="labels">
        <label for="slide1" class="label">text slide 1</label>
        <label for="slide2" class="label">text slide 2</label>
        <label for="slide3" class="label">text slide 3</label>
      
        <div class="fake-radio">
          <label for="slide1" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <label for="slide2" class="radio-btn"></label>
          <label for="slide3" class="radio-btn"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is really good, but i also need that works on mobile and this codepen when you use the dots it won't be anymore autoplay.